# Sitara AM335x (Beaglebone Green) - programming the cortex m3

Tags: beagleboneblack, cortex-m, texas-instruments

currently im working on a baremetal application on a beaglebone green, which has the AM3358, containing
an A8 processor, two PRUs and a cortex M3.

Because im using a Segger J-Link EDU as a programmer, i cant connect to the two PRUs. So im not able to use/ debug them in my application (The IDE im using is Code Composer Studio by the way).

Programming the A8 is working, but i want to use the Cortex M3 as a co-processor, to let him do
some communication stuff, like UART, SPI etc. I have searched for similar projects, but was only able
to find the information, that the cortex M3 is preloaded with a firmware, which does power management.

Has anyone done a similar project and can provide me some infos, about accessing peripherals through the m3 and if the whole system is running, when the m3 is loaded with a new application?